# change the path of index file from public to some other folder in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to run the index.html file in react like this **..public/myapp/index.html** instead of defalut **..public/index.html**

I tried like below but its not working

```
my-app/
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
        myapp/
             index.html
             favicon.ico
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Please share your App.js and index.js

Comment: You have to configure your webpack configurations I think.